# HTTP 500 when accessing Kibana on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, saml, elk

I'm using elasticsearch and kibana both managed by AWS, I've configured SAML with ADFS to authenticate my users, but some users login successfully by accessing Kibana, while others login fails and shows the following message:

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Internal Error"}
```

Analyzing the errors in the browser I found something about SameSite, but I believe the SameSite error should happen to everyone.

[image]

Is there anything you can do in Kibana to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

if this is the aws Elasticsearch service you will need to contact their support. they run forks of Elasticsearch and Kibana and their own plugins to handle security that are not source available or community supported